# How do I insert an array into database table?

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, pg

I have the following Ruby code:

```
 94   def open_connection(info)
 95     self.log "opening #{info.inspect}"
 96     db = Mysql.init
 97     db.options(Mysql::SET_CHARSET_NAME, 'utf8')
 98     db.real_connect(info.host, info.user, info.password, info.dbname, info.port)
 99     db.query("SET NAMES utf8")
100 »···res = db.query("SELECT realname FROM profiles")
101 
102 »···conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "dbname", "user", "pwd")
```

How do I take the `res` variable and loop through it to insert it into my Postgres database?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using an ORM, except for the most trivial of DB tasks. I like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), but [Datamapper](http://datamapper.org/) and [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/) are good also. The big win with a good ORM, is your code doesn't change when you need to switch to a different DBM, you just point it and it goes.

Comment: @theTinMan: The downside of an ORM is that it is a lot of wasted effort for a one-off and it can be difficult to get them to talk to two different databases at the same time. ORMs also tend to have problems with database-specific data types (such as PostgreSQL's rich but non-standard types) and advanced SQL features (such as triggers and window functions). I'll qualify this by noting that most of my Ruby ORM experience is (unfortunately) with ActiveRecord, the others might have better attitudes and be less limited.

Comment: FWIW, [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/index.html) is not hard to get to talk to multiple databases, and I feel that there is generally less typing for the same work as raw SQL statements. It's win-win (and no, using just it's datasets it's not really a full ORM, which is why it can be so efficient and easy to use).

Comment: @theTinMan: "your code doesn't change when you need to switch to a different DBM", you really should know better than that, a quick "ruby-on-rails postgresql heroku" search is all you need to see how portable ORMs are between databases.

Comment: "The downside of an ORM is that it is a lot of wasted effort for a one-off", that's why I said "except for the most trivial of DB tasks". I've had no problem getting Sequel to talk to multiple DBs and/or servers. ActiveRecord does have its opinions, which is why I use Sequel, because it doesn't get in my way.

Comment: @muistooshort "your code doesn't change when you need to switch to a different DBM", I have used Sequel for many projects without any problem switching between SQLite, MySQL and Postgres. Perhaps you should give it a try.

Comment: @theTinMan: I intend to, I'd love a good excuse to set ActiveRecord on fire and forget that it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL `query` method gives you a `Mysql::Result` instance so you can use [`each`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/Mysql/Result#each-instance_method) to get each row as an Array:

```
res = db.query('select realname from profiles')
res.each do |a|
    # a is an array of strings
    realname = a.first
    # ...
end
```

If you had more columns in the result set then [`each_hash`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/Mysql/Result#each_hash-instance_method) might be easier to work with, that calls the block with a Hash which maps column names to their values.

To insert data into PostgreSQL, use [`exec`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#exec-instance_method):

```
pg_conn.exec('insert into some_table (some_column) values ($1)', [ realname ])
```

Please use placeholders rather than interpolation, there's no need to party like PHP programmers in 1999.

You could also use [`prepare`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#prepare-instance_method) and [`exec_prepared`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#exec_prepared-instance_method):

```
pg_conn.prepare('ins', 'insert into some_table (some_column) values ($1)')
pg_conn.exec_prepared('ins', [ realname1 ])
pg_conn.exec_prepared('ins', [ realname2 ])
# ...
```

The `prepare` approach is better if you're going to be executing the same SQL over and over again.

Combining them gets the job done:

```
res = db.query('select realname from profiles')
pg_conn.prepare('ins', 'insert into some_table (some_column) values ($1)')
res.each { |a| pg_conn.exec_prepared('ins', a) }
```

Comment: so do:
 
res = db.query('select realname from profiles')

res.each do |a|
    realname = a.first
end

pg_conn.prepare('ins', 'insert into some_table (some_column) values ($1)')
res.each { |a| pg_conn.exec_prepared('ins', a) }

Is this correct?

Comment: @wonbyte: You don't need the `res.each do |a| # a is an...`, just `res = db.query(...); pg_conn.prepare('ins', ...); res.each { |a| ... }`.

Comment: So the first line of your code at the top and then the last two lines at the bottom?

Sorry, Brand new to Ruby

Comment: @wonbyte: Yeah, the `res.each` in the first chunk of code is for illustrative purposes.

Comment: I have

pg_conn.prepare('users', 'INSERT INTO users (mail) VALUES ($1)')
108 »···res.each { |a| pg_conn.exec_prepared('users', a) }

but It's not putting the data in. Any suggestions?

Comment: res = db.query("SELECT login_name FROM profiles") is coming back with about 50 email address.

Comment: Does that PostgreSQL table have any other columns? Do they allow NULLs?

Comment: If I want to insert more than one option does the pg_conn.prepare become pg_conn.prepare('ins', 'insert into some_table (some_column, another_column) values ($1, $2)')?

Comment: @wonbyte: Yes, the column names after the table name match up with the `values` which match up with the supplied Ruby array.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/index.html) DB library you can either use [`import`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-import):

```
# When `res` is an array of just values
res = MYSQLDB[:profiles].select_map(:realname)
PGDB[:profiles].import([:realname],res)
```

…or you can use [`multi_insert`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-multi_insert):

```
# When `res` is an array of hashes mapping column name to value
res = MYSQLDB[:profiles].select(:realname).all
PGDB[:profiles].multi_insert(res)
```

With either of the above you can optionally pass a last parameter with the option to insert in batches (which may use less memory and be more performant as a result):

```
PGDB[:profiles].import([:realname],res,commit_every:500)
PGDB[:profiles].multi_insert(res,commit_every:500)
```

Comment: +1. Excellent examples of why I use Sequel, and why it's so nice.